# União de 2 SELECTs diferentes - SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Como consigo unir esses dois SELECTs?

SELECT 1:

```
SELECT
TOTENERGIA /100 AS 'Totalizador Energia'
, TOTVAZAO /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão'
, TOTENERGIA1016 /100 AS 'Totalizador Energia 1016'
, TOTVAZAO1016 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazâo 1016'
, TOTVAZAOTM1 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1'
, TOTVAZAOTM2 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2'
, convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121) AS 'HORA'
FROM
TableETE
WHERE
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'MM') = 12
AND(FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') >= '10:00:00' AND FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') <= '10:00:04' AND TOTENERGIA IS NOT NULL
OR FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') >= '16:00:00' AND FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') <= '16:00:04' AND TOTENERGIA IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
[HORA] DESC
```

SELECT 2:

```
SELECT  AVG(TOCPERMEADO /100) 'Media TOC'
, (convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121))
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE 
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'MM') = 12 AND
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '16:00:04'
GROUP BY
convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121)
```

Comment: Não poderia ser a média dos dois valores por data (truncando) ? SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12),HORA, 101) DATA,AVG(TOCPERMEADO) MEDIA
FROM TableETE GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(12),HORA, 101)

Comment: @Motta Pior que não preciso do TotalEnergia das 10:00 e 16:00 no relatório!

Comment: Não entendi, desculpe-me.

Comment: Tente com Analytic Functions OVER ou um joins destas duas sqls como tabelas virtuais

Comment: Consegui com Cross Join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Única forma que consegui foi usando um Cross Join:

```
SELECT  AVG(TOCPERMEADO /100) AS 'Media TOC'
, (convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121)) AS 'DATA'
INTO #TEMP1
FROM 
TableETE
WHERE 
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'MM') = 12 AND
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '16:00:04'
GROUP BY
convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121)
SELECT
TOTENERGIA /100 AS 'Totalizador Energia'
, TOTVAZAO /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão'
, TOTENERGIA1016 /100 AS 'Totalizador Energia 1016'
, TOTVAZAO1016 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazâo 1016'
, TOTVAZAOTM1 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM1'
, TOTVAZAOTM2 /100 AS 'Totalizador Vazão TM2'
, (convert(char(10), DIASHORAS, 121)) AS 'DATA'
, convert(char(13), DIASHORAS, 121)+ ':00' AS 'HORA'
INTO #TEMP2
FROM
TableETE
WHERE
FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'MM') = 12
AND(FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') >= '10:00:00' AND FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') <= '10:00:04' AND TOTENERGIA IS NOT NULL
OR FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') >= '16:00:00' AND FORMAT (DIASHORAS, 'HH:mm:ss') <= '16:00:04' AND TOTENERGIA IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
[HORA] DESC
SELECT * #TEMP1 CROSS JOIN #TEMP2 ORDER BY [HORA] DESC
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).